# C# and OpenOffice to export slides from Powerpoint presentation as images

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openoffice-impress

In C# you can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint to open a .ppt and export its slides as images. But you need to have Office installed on the computer. (And I dont want to use Aspose)

I can also export slides from a .ppt using OpenOffice Impress.

Is there something like "OpenOffice.Interop.Impress" which lets me do the same thing?

Comment: C# doesn't appear to be one of the supported scripting languages for OpenOffice: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Scripting_Framework

Comment: Another language would be fine. But it looks like scripting is only accessible from inside OpenOffice. What I want to do is, run an assembly or script from inside my own application to automatically export the slides.

Comment: I was a little surprised to find this, but it appears that there is an automation API for OpenOffice: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Bridge/Automation_Bridge